# Guzzle Pool doesn't respect timeout

Tags: php, asynchronous, request, timeout, guzzle

I have some problem with my guzzle client. I set timeout for example 1.0 and in some route I do sleep(5). Guzzle anyway wait on response when should just throw exception.
client:

```
$requests[] = new Request('GET', $path, [
        'timeout' => 1,
        'connect_timeout' => 1
    ]);

$pool = new Pool($this->client, $requests, [
        'concurrency' => 5,
        'fulfilled' => function ($response, $index) use ($response_merger) {
            $response_merger->fulfilled($response);
        },
        'rejected' => function ($reason, $index) use ($response_merger) {
            $response_merger->error($reason);
        }
    ]);
```

and my route with delay:

```
$app->get('/timeout', function() use ($app) {
    sleep(5);
    return (new JsonResponse())->setData([ 'error' => 'My timeout exception.' ])->setStatusCode(504);
});
```

I always get 504 with My timeout exception, when I should not get it because timeout is set.

I did it with set client, but it is not a solution for me because I need custom timeout for certain request, not client.

```
$this->client = new Client([
        'timeout'  => 3.0,
        'connect_timeout'  => 1.0
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `timeout` as an option when constructing the `Pool`:

```
$pool = new Pool($this->client, $requests, [
    'concurrency' => 5,
    'options' => ['timeout' => 10],
    'fulfilled' => function ($response, $index) use ($response_merger) {
        $response_merger->fulfilled($response);
    },
    'rejected' => function ($reason, $index) use ($response_merger) {
        $response_merger->error($reason);
    }
]);
```

Found this in comments of the `Pool` code [here](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Pool.php).

Comment: Testing with Guzzle 7.0.1 it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got the wrong signature in mind for `new Request()`. From the docs:

```
// Create a PSR-7 request object to send
$headers = ['X-Foo' => 'Bar'];
$body = 'Hello!';
$request = new Request('HEAD', 'http://httpbin.org/head', $headers, $body);
```

The third parameter is for HTTP headers, not options.